# Upgrade Famas on round 4

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

Let's say you win the first 3 rounds as CT and at the start of the 4th round you have a Famas and you know the enemy team will buy.

Is it bad to not upgrade your Famas (To M4) even if you have the money? How much of a disadvantage is it considered to face AK's with a Famas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Famas](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/FAMAS) are worse than [M4A1-S](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/M4A1-S). Famas are slower to reload, give you a worse movement speed and do less damage. The have the same rounds per second.

[AK](http://counterstrike.wikia.com/wiki/AK-47)s are slower to fire, reload and move with than the other two, but are more likely to do fatal damage from one shot.

Given these stats it seems you will have a marginal advantage chosing the M4A1-S. You'll be able to move and reload more quickly, and do more damage.

But I think the real problem is the human factor, at least how I play :D I'm always shooting at knees.

So to answer your question about value for money: the stats suggest that upgrading will be of negligable benefit. Stick with the Famas.

Comment: Do you think it's better to use your money to get an M4 or save the money and just roll with the Famas? If it was a Bizon or another SMG i will always upgrade on round 4 but im not sure on the Famas. I seem to do pretty good with it against a full buying team if not just as good as when i have an M4.

Comment: @g00ns see my edit :)

Answer (score 1):

The standard professional play is to pick up a M4/AK on Round 3. If you have sufficient money to also get Keylar+Helmet and grenades on Round 2, it's also acceptable to pick it up then too, but you must play safely with it. This is because teams were often greedily trying to continue using SMG's in Round 3, which could be beaten pretty readily by a forced buy from their opponents. Buying M4/AK at the start of Round 3 is more consistent and makes these forced buys very difficult for your opponents.

In round 4, unless you're extremely comfortable with the FAMAS, you should absolutely be upgrading to a more powerful rifle.